# IOS api call continuously

Tags: ios, api

If I have a app in which the user can set remainders for when there is a new article in a blog. And we can find out if there is a new article in the blog by sending a api request. How should I make the app to continuously send requests to the api. Is there an other way to do this or should we just keep sending requests to api continuously. And if so in how much time interval should we send it.

Thanks

Comment: Do not make continuous API calls to a server. That is bad for many reasons. It wastes bandwidth and user's data plans. It kills the battery. Polling is rarely a good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case delegating the check for updates to some sort of server side would be ideal. The server side logic could send push notifications to your clients.

Comment: Have a look at parse.com, it's an excellent backend solution with push notifications, etc, etc.